# Gradient backgrounds work in iOS 8 but not iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, ios8

So I'm building a table view centric app, and I'm trying to include a gradient background for each table view cell, using the following code:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.84 blue:0.49 alpha:1.0]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.86 blue:0.61 alpha:1.0]CGColor], nil];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.51 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];
```

Now, in the simulator that I am using, which is running iOS 8 (using Xcode 6 Beta 2), I get this result: 
[image]

But on my device (sorry for the Assistive touch, my lock button is broken...), running iOS 7, it looks like this:

[image]

My gradients throughout the app in the main view background work on both, it's just the gradients in the table cell views that don't work. As you can also see in these screenshots, the section header views also have gradients, but these work in both versions. Is there a certain flag I need to be looking for to make this work in iOS 7?

Edit: 
This is being called in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.94 green:0.84 blue:0.49 alpha:1.0]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.86 blue:0.61 alpha:1.0]CGColor], nil];
[cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.25 green:0.51 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];

NSDictionary *match;
if(indexPath.section == 0) {
    match = [_inprogressMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else if(indexPath.section == 1) {
    match = [_finalMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else {
    match = [_pregameMatches objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

NSDictionary *homeTeam = [match objectForKey:@"homeTeamId"];
NSDictionary *awayTeam = [match objectForKey:@"awayTeamId"];    
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ : %@ %@",[awayTeam objectForKey:@"name"] , [match objectForKey:@"awayScore"], [match objectForKey:@"homeScore"], [homeTeam objectForKey:@"name"]];

return cell;
}
```

Comment: Show more code, please. Where is that code being called? Show the full context.

Comment: You are also showing to different OS versions (7 and 8). Does it look the same on the iOS 7 Simulator and the iOS 8 Simulator?

Comment: Why are you not setting the cell's backgroundView? There is really no need to mess with its layer like this, and you are probably doing it wrong in any case (you're probably adding the layer over and over, even if the cell already has the layer - though it is hard to be sure, as you have not shown enough code).

Comment: I agree with @DavidRönnqvist - why aren't you using an iOS 7 simulator?

Comment: So in the iOS 7 simulator, the same thing happens, I'm going to double check now though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put a gradient in the background of a cell, don't mess with its layer (which you are doing wrong in any case, since you are not checking for the existence of the layer in a reused cell).

Give the cell a `backgroundView` whose layer is the gradient or has the gradient as sublayer. That is what `backgroundView` is for.

Comment: so doing something like:        [cell.backgroundView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
 doesn't seem to work in the iOS 8 simulator either. Is this what you were suggesting I do?

Comment: You have to _make_ the background view. Actual code in my discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_registering_a_cell_class

Comment: Awesome, thanks matt! This worked like a charm. The link above has everything I needed